# Filepicker.io - Pick and Store upload files two times

Tags: filepicker.io

Currently implementing Filepicker in my project.

When using the `pickAndStore` function with the javascript lib, the file appears twice in my console but only once in S3.

Any idea?

Here is my code :

```
filepicker.setKey('XXX');

filepicker.pickAndStore({
  multiple: true,
  services: ['DROPBOX', 'FACEBOOK', 'INSTAGRAM', 'FLICKR', 'GOOGLE_DRIVE', 'BOX', 'PICASA']
}, {}, function(fpfiles) {
  var i, photos;
  photos = new Array();
  i = 0;
  while (i < fpfiles.length) {
    photos[i] = new Object();
    photos[i].url = fpfiles[i].url;
    i++;
  }
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/some/url",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      photos: photos
    })
  }).always(function() {
    return location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to when this is happening? I.e. is it occurring on all uploads, just ones from the computer, from facebook, etc?

Comment: Seems to happen everytime, tested Dropbox and Facebook. I've added my code, maybe am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure it's related to the pickAndStore function. The photos are stored both in my S3 bucket and in yours, can I configure to store only on my S3 bucket?

Comment: What's occurring is that the first file link is pointing to the original Dropbox, facebook, etc. file, while the second one is referring to the copy of the file that is stored in your S3. I've confirmed with the team that this is a reporting issue on our front in terms of what is shown on your developer portal, but does not impact billing

Comment: So the file is counted only once, meaning I can have up to 10'000 files in my dashboard with the free plan?

Comment: Another question, how can I do to NOT generate a link pointing to the original files in Dropbox, Facebook?

Comment: Still want to know if it is possible to NOT generate a link pointing to the original file. Thanks

Comment: Hi there - this is being addressed in our next release, we will let you know when it has been resolved

Comment: Good news! Thanks for the support Brett.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved and is no longer the case. Only one file link will be created and show up in your developer console. Thank you for the suggestion!